# What's the error in following code snippet of jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
$("#ckbCheckAll").click(function () {   

  $('div .bulkop .ez-checkbox').toggleClass("ez-checked", this.checked);

    var id_checkboxes = $('div .bulkop .ez-checkbox input').map(function() {
      return this.id;
    }).get();
   for (var i = 0; i < id_checkboxes.length; i++) {
   if (('#'+id_checkboxes[i]).is(':checked')) { 
        ('#'+id_checkboxes[i]).removeAttr('checked');
      }
      else{ //alert("In Else");
        ('#'+id_checkboxes[i]).attr('checked');
      }
 }
 });
```

I'm getting the following error in console:

```
TypeError: id_checkboxes[i].val is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

if (("#"+id_checkboxes[i].val()).is(':checked')) {
```

Comment: What are you trying to achive with this `("#"+id_checkboxes[i].val()).is(':checked')` line?

Comment: Ignoring the specific error (various answers below), your code is a little *obscure*... can you explain what the overall aim is?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)?

```
$("#ckbCheckAll").click(function () {
    $('div .bulkop .ez-checkbox').toggleClass("ez-checked", this.checked);

    $('div .bulkop .ez-checkbox input').each(function() {
        $(this).prop('checked', !$(this).is(':checked')); //Toggle "checked"
    });
});
```

Comment: `checkboxes[i]` will be the native DOM element - you need to convert it to a jQuery object.

Comment: +1 for using `prop` instead of `attr` for a checkbox... This is in my opinion the first answer that is actually closest to correct.

Comment: Couldn't you just write `this.checked = !this.checked` instead of `$(this).prop('checked', !$(this).is(':checked'))` ?

Comment: @Matteo Tassinari: No point mixing elements and JQuery when JQuery can actually do it all without the each. Just waiting for someone to post the most elegant answer - yours is now close :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the method [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns the native DOM elements collection, and not a jQuery object.

So, since it is not a jQuery object, it does not have the [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method.

Hence, the line

```
("#"+id_checkboxes[i].val()).is(':checked')
```

should actually be

```
$("#"+$(id_checkboxes[i]).val()).is(':checked') // added "$" in front
```

but I would replace the whole handler as

```
$("#ckbCheckAll").click(function () {
    $('div .bulkop .ez-checkbox')
        .toggleClass("ez-checked", this.checked)
        .find('input')
        .prop('checked', this.checked); //Toggle "checked" to the same state of #ckbCheckAll
});
```

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Krh9S/2/

Comment: `$("#"+id_checkboxes[i].val())` statement will not work i guess.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie why wrong? Feel free to correct it yourself =)

Comment: I stand corrected... without the HTML the layout was guesswork, but after creating this fiddle I now choose you as the most correct answer: http://jsfiddle.net/Krh9S/2/ (I also cleaned out my old comments as they no longer mean anything).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie thanks for making the fiddle and for your upvote =)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `$(string selector)` with jQuery($)

Change

```
  ("#"+id_checkboxes[i].val())
```

to

```
 $("#"+id_checkboxes[i]).val()
```

Then

```
('#'+id_checkboxes[i]).is(':checked')
```

to

```
$('#'+id_checkboxes[i]).is(':checked')
```

NOTE:

You can't call `val()` like `"#"+id_checkboxes[i].val()`, since `id_checkboxes[i] is string`

Also you cant do `$("#"+id_checkboxes[i].val()).is(':checked')`